# Convert from 'fr_FR' type language codes to ISO 639-2 language codes

Tags: java, localization, locale, iso

I need to convert in Java from strings like `fr_FR`, `en_GB`, `ja_JP` (meaning the French, English, and Japanese  language) to their ISO 639-2 representations: `fre/fra`, `eng`, `jpn`.

Do you know if the notation style `fr_FR` complies to a certain standard? I haven't found anything in this regard.

Do you know how can I make the conversion from this notation to ISO 639-2 (3-letter) language codes?

Thanks a lot!

Update: I know the method getISO3Language(). And I also know that I could construct, by iterating the available locales, strings like `fr_FR` and then make a mapping with the ISO 639-2 3-letter code - thus, whenever I search for a 3-letter code I can find in the map I constructed. The thing is that I would fit me much better a direct solution. Sorry that I didn't explained this from the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This too long for a comment so...

> Do you know if the notation style
>   fr_FR complies to a certain standard?
>   I haven't found anything in this
>   regard.

The first two letters are the language code:

> The language argument is a valid ISO
>   Language Code. These codes are the
>   lower-case, two-letter codes as
>   defined by ISO-639.

The last two letters are the country code:

> The country argument is a valid ISO
>   Country Code. These codes are the
>   upper-case, two-letter codes as
>   defined by ISO-3166.

So now you have found something in this regard, that explains to which standards this notation corresponds.

Comment: To embellish this, en_GB means English spoken in the UK, fr_FR means the French spoken in France. en_US or en_EN (I can never remember which, it may even vary from vendor to vendor) means the English spoken in the USA, fr_CA means the French spoken in Canada.

Comment: @Rich: with 2K+ rep you can embellish my answer by editing it if you want :)

Comment: Thanks guys! Indeed, the notation is composed by concatenating 2 strings complying 2 standards. This concatenation for sure it's not a standard on its own.

Comment: ) I'm not a fan of editing other people's answers unless there's something wrong with them (the answer, not the answerer) as it can hide the original answerer's answer. At least this way your answer is all your own work!

Comment: The "Country Code" can also be "region designator", like '419' for Latin America and can also be a script designator like 'Hans' for Chinese but written in simplified script. For an explanation see e.g. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LanguageandLocaleIDs/LanguageandLocaleIDs.html

Answer (score 6):

You can see the notation style `{language}_{country}` in the javadoc of [java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(String, Locale, ClassLoader)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29), so it won't be so bad to use the notation style. On the other hand, it also should be noted that *language tags* have `{language}-{country}` style (not underscore '_' but hyphen '-'). Detailed description can be found in the javadoc of [java.util.Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html).

A simple way to convert `{language}_{country}` to ISO 639-2 (3-letter) code is `new Locale(str.substring(0,2)).getISO3Language()`, but it seems you are looking for another way like the following:

```
String locale = "fr_FR";

try
{
    // LanguageAlpha3Code is a Java enum that represents ISO 639-2 codes.
    LanguageAlpha3Code alpha3;

    // LocaleCode.getByCode(String) [static method] accepts a string
    // whose format is {language}, {language}_{country}, or
    // {language}-{country} where {language} is IS0 639-1 (2-letter)
    // and {country} is ISO 3166-1 alpha2 code (2-letter) and returns
    // a LocaleCode enum. LocaleCode.getLanguage() [instance method]
    // returns a LanguageCode enum. Finally, LanguageCode.getAlpha3()
    // returns a LanguageAlpha3Code enum.
    alpha3 = LocaleCode.getByCode(locale).getLanguage().getAlpha3();

    // French has two ISO 639-2 codes. One is "terminology" code
    // (ISO 639-2/T) and the other is "bibliographic" code
    // (ISO 639-2/B). 2 lines below prints "fra" for ISO 639-2/T
    // and "fre" for ISO 639-2/B.
    System.out.println("ISO 639-2/T: " + alpha3.getAlpha3T());
    System.out.println("ISO 639-2/B: " + alpha3.getAlpha3B());
}
catch (NullPointerException e)
{
    System.out.println("Unknown locale: " + locale);
}
```

The example above can be run with **nv-i18n** internationalization package. If you are using Maven, try to add the dependency below to your pom.xml,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.neovisionaries</groupId>
    <artifactId>nv-i18n</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

or download nv-i18n's jar from [Maven Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C-627365529) directly.

nv-i18n source code and javadoc are hosted on GitHub.

Source: https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-i18n
Javadoc: http://takahikokawasaki.github.com/nv-i18n/

Answer (score 3):

Create a Locale object then use `getISO3Language()`.
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getISO3Language()

```
String lang="fr", country="FR", convertedLang;
Locale l = new Locale(lang, country);
convertedLang= l.getISO3Language(); // should be what you're after
```

Comment: Thanks! I know the method. I updated my question to reflect more clearly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

This is all discussed in the documentation of java.util.Locale. The two-letter codes are also from the ISO standards, and Locale has a method getISO3Language() that does what you want.

Comment: Thanks! I know the method. I updated my question to reflect more clearly what I want.